# Any time I try to develop anything with Solana, the Phantom wallet creates false positive warnings due to Blowfish

Tags: phantom

I am trying to create a presale for our crypto project on Solana. I tried to even send a blank transaction (not transferring a single penny), just to see see what is triggering blowfish. Can somebody please explain why this is happening? I've reached out to blowfish support through email and submitted issues on github.

We've made it very clear what our intentions are with the actual transaction too. It sends a transaction on the solana blockchain, stores the current price of solana on the blockchain, notifies the backend and updates the amount of tokens the user will receive upon token launch.

Our community is very excited to join the presale, but we have to keep postponing it because of blowfish. We have a lot of work to do to add utility to our project, but we are stuck due to this issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The solution is to contact review@blowfish.xyz. Thank you for the prompt and effective solution.